# Is three.js gives direct support for usdz format?

Tags: three.js, 3d-model, usdz

I want to 3d model to show in my react.js website but I am getting the file format as usdz, does three.js gives the support for the other format too.

I tried using three-usdz-loader npm module and other loader from three.js but giving error and not working

Comment: You should add what code you did write that didn't work. A quick glance at threeJS reveals it does support it, so in order to be helped you need to share. Be happy @ŁukaszDMastalerz already gave you the example, but post your own code please.